# goto 3rd party link using SSO from Salesforce using HTTP Post

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, http

Can anyone help me with redirecting user **to 3rd party** server **using SSO from SALESFORCE using Apex class using HTTP Post**.

Any links will also help..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this 3rd party application supports SAML or oAuth, then you should use a connected app: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_overview.htm